# Canonical Resource URLs Across a Multisite Network 2012?

Tags: multisite, htaccess, domain-mapping

This question was asked back in 2010 @

[Outputting Canonical Resource URLs Across a Multisite Network?](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/5896/outputting-canonical-resource-urls-across-a-multisite-network)

[WordPress MU Domain Mapping @ Wordpress.org](http://wordpress.org/support/topic/plugin-wordpress-mu-domain-mapping-normalizing-resource-url-with-filter?replies=2)

Since many things have changed since then, I was wondering what would be the best method to do this now. Would it be easier/better to just use .htaccess rules or in a varnish VCL?

I want to normalize plugin/theme files accross all of the sites on the network without using any host file hacks and works with the domain mapping plugin. I am using the subdirectory install and also a CDN. Thank you for any help/examples. This is my first post, but long time lurker ;)

P.S. If themes/plugins would need to be manually edited, would it be easier to create a plugin with all of the rules that can be network activated?

Comment: +1 for doing with `.htaccess`, Nginx rewrites, Varnish VCL or whatever the tool you have in the server-side. I don't know, if it is possible with a plugin, but I'm sure it can be done on the server end.

Comment: I'm thinking it may work out better to keep it away from the webserver and push it up to the next level to minimize problems. I'm playing with Varnish VCL and mod_pagespeed, but still have not worked out a solution that works for all themes/plugins yet. There are a lot of factors in play, and they don't always play nice